# Use Hibernate Connection across multiple requests and let user commit or rollback

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I would like to create a page in my web application where the user can (somewhat) freely execute some queries, like select and updates.
I'm using Hibernate 3.6.10
The user should be able to commit and rollback.
Right now if a request ends without a commit or rollback the connection is rolled back:

```
WLTC0033W: Resource jdbc/... rolled back in cleanup of LocalTransactionContainment
```

How can i prevent that and use the connection across multiple requests?

Comment: Why are you using Hibernate? Can the user enter HQL?

Comment: No, the rest of the software uses hibernate, so the best practice seemed to be using hibernate for this as well. But it's not mandatory